# Python read in string from file and split it into column names and values

Tags: python

I have a raw data file in the below format with multiple rows:

```
NAME: Jack Age : 25   skill : c++ designation : Analyst other comments:this 
is basic info

NAME : Kattie Age: 45 skill: python  designation: director Other Comments: name : Jane Kattie
```

I want output as :

```
    name    age skill   designation  other_Comments      name_2 
0   Jack    25  c++     analyst      This is basic Info  NA
1   Kattie  45  python  Director      NA                 Jane Kattie
```

I have tried using below codes but unable to handle special cases like row 2, i am new to python, please suggest if there is any better way , the key words are definite set of values, but may repeat more than once.

Codes:

```
file =pd.read_excel('mydata.xlsx', sheetname="Sheet1", header=None)
file.columns =['data']

for i in range(0,len(file)):
     x=file[file.columns.values [0]][i]  
     name= re.findall(r'Name:(.*?)Age',x)
     Age= re.findall(r'Age(.*?) skill',x)
     skills= re.findall(r'skill(.*?)designation',x)
     other_Comments = re.findall(r'other comments(.*?),x)
     file['Name'][i] = name
     file['Age'][i] = Age
     file['Skill'][i] = skills
     file ['Other_Comments'][i] = other_Comments
```

Comment: Show us what code you have so far - how are you reading the text in from the file? What file format is it? What went wrong with the list function? You could [str.split(":")](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each line if you know that the "titles" (e.g. NAME) will always be the same and in the same place? Show us that you've tried first then we'll help you if you run into trouble :-)

Comment: sure, let me share the current codes

Answer (score 0):

Python has a separate module for handling csv files:

import csv

For more information about how to use it, I recommend going to the python.org website. There you'll find all you need about how to use it.